# Seeing a weird navigation behavior in modern team site linked to hubsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, team-sites, hub-site

I am working with SP Online in modern experience and many team sites created and linked to HubSite "Home", the hub navigation shows perfectly fine.

Since last couple of days, I am seeing another row of weird navigation in a row below hub nav and I have no idea where this comes from.
[image]

Can't enable publishing features on team site modern, so navigation option is not even showing up under site settings, so how can it appear all of a sudden, was not showing up before at all.

Can someone please assist, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, one of the users had actually added navigation links and I got to know about it from site settings page, just clicked on edit links and took them off.